Summation identity with Zeta function and Stirling numbers
I have found an identity that I am pretty confident is true, namely:
$$\sum_{0 < i_1 < \dotsb < i_r}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{i_1\dotsb i_r}\frac{1}{(i_r+1)^2}}
= r + 1 - \sum_{k=2}^{r+1}{\zeta(k)}\;\;\; \text{ for }r\geq1$$
I have proved it for $r = 1, 2$ and checked it by computer for higher values of $r$.
Comments:

The right-hand side can be re-written as $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^\infty{\frac{1}{k(k+1)^r}}$.

The left-hand side is equal to $\displaystyle \sum_{k=r}^\infty{\left[k \atop r\right] \frac{1}{(k+1)\cdot(k+1)!}}$, where $\left[\;\right]$ denotes Stirling numbers of the first kind. (Do this by placing $k = i_r$, then instead of choosing $r-1$ numbers to divide, choose $k-r$ to multiply, dividing by $(k-1)!$).


Any help or suggestions for proving the identity are greatly appreciated!

Look into the phrase “multiple zeta values”, that should get you some relevant information.

Thanks! It worked by an application of the duality theorem in MZV

We prove this by induction on $r$. The case $r=1$ is straightforward.
Let $a_r$ denote the left-hand side and $b_r$ the right-hand side.  We can see $b_r - b_{r+1} = \zeta(r+2) - 1$. If we prove $a_r - a_{r+1}$ is equal to this also, we are done.
$$a_r - a_{r+1} =
\sum_{i_r > \dotsb > i_1 > 0}{
  \frac{1}{i_1\dotsb i_r} 
  \left(\frac{1}{(i_r+1)^2} - \sum_{i_{r+1} > i_r} \frac{1}{i_{r+1}(i_{r+1}+1)^2}\right)
} =
\sum_{i_r > \dotsb > i_1 > 0}{
  \frac{1}{i_1\dotsb i_r} 
  \left(\sum_{i_{r+1} > i_r}{\frac{1}{i_{r+1}^2}-\frac{1}{i_r+1}}\right)
} =
\zeta(2, \{1\}^r) - c_r
$$
Where $\zeta$ is the multiple zeta values (MZV) function, $\{1\}^r$ means the argument $1$ repeated $r$ times, and we defined the following:
$$c_r = \displaystyle \sum{k \geq 1}{\frac{1}{k(k+1)} S^{r-1}_k}$$
$$S^r_N := \displaystyle \sum_{0 < i_1 < \dotsb < i_r < N}{\frac{1}{i_1\dotsb i_r}}$$
Using a theorem about the MZV, as proved in section 3 of this paper, we get that $\zeta(2, \{1\}^r) = \zeta(r+2)$.
Finally, $c_r$ can be shown to be equal to $1$ by induction. (Prove $c_1 = 1$, then $c_{r+1} = c_r$).
